# return RedirectToAction() not passing object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two partialViews in my ASP.NET MVC4 Application-

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Autocomplete_Search(string accountHead, List<LedgerModel> ledge)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountHead)) {
        ledge = (from u in db.LedgerTables
                 where u.AccountHead.Contains(accountHead) && u.FKRegisteredRecord == this.LoggedInUser.RegisterID
                 select new LedgerModel {
                     AccID = u.AccID,
                     Place = u.Place,
                     AccountHead = u.AccountHead,
                     DateAccountHead = Convert.ToDateTime(u.DateAccountHead) != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(u.DateAccountHead) : DateTime.Now

                 }).ToList();
        return RedirectToAction("_ProductSearchList", ledge);

    }
    return View();
    //return Json(ledge, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**And-**

```
public ActionResult _ProductSearchList(List<LedgerModel> ledge) {
            List<LedgerModel> ledger = null;
            if (ledge != null) {
                ledger = (from u in ledge
                         select new LedgerModel {
                             AccID = u.AccID,
                             Place = u.Place,
                             AccountHead = u.AccountHead,
                             DateAccountHead = Convert.ToDateTime(u.DateAccountHead) != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(u.DateAccountHead) : DateTime.Now

                         }).ToList();

                return PartialView(ledge);
            }
            else {
                return PartialView(ledge);
            }
        }
```

Okay now when I send string through a textbox, Action `AutoComplete_Search` is called. At the time of redirection to another method named `_ProductSearchList` I am sending an object `ledge` of listType to This method. But It says `ledge` null in `_ProductSearchList` action's parameters.

However this object is a list type and contains records. How do I get this object `ledge` which is redirected to action `_ProductSearchList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for giving time on this issue.

As @Damian S described about  `complex object redirecting` is notable advice for me.

However I was able to find simplest solution to this problem to use `DataDictionary` in `C#`.

I managed it with using `TempData[]` to store details in easiest way I guess because it is most Precise and trivial technique.

**Using `TempData[]`**

Storing record in TempData[] in `AutoComplete_Search() controller`-

```
TempData["Records"]= ledge;
```

**Usage in `ProductSearchList` controller**

```
List<ledgerModel> ledge= (List<ledgerModel>)TempData["Records"];
```

Solved my problem and headache of playing with objects `methods` to `methods`.!

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter taken by [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291.aspx) is not a model, it is a route.
That's why you are not receiving what you expect in your `_ProductSearchList` action.

I'm not quite sure that something like this would work because i don't know how a list of complex objects could be serialized in the url (or even if this is recommanded), but here is what would be expected :

```
return RedirectToAction("_ProductSearchList", new { ledge = ledge });
```

To pass your list, you have the [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) option (quote from MSDN) :

> An action method can store data in the controller's TempDataDictionary
>   object before it calls the controller's RedirectToAction method to
>   invoke the next action. The TempData property value is stored in
>   session state. Any action method that is called after the
>   TempDataDictionary value is set can get values from the object and
>   then process or display them. The value of TempData persists until it
>   is read or until the session times out. Persisting TempData in this
>   way enables scenarios such as redirection, because the values in
>   TempData are available beyond a single request.

Don't forget to take a look at [Using Tempdata in ASP.NET MVC - Best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422930/using-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-best-practice) before using it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first you can`t get List ledge in get request in Autocomplete_Search.

You can`t pass complex object in redirecting. You can only pass a simple scalar value.

Check answer in this thread:

[send data between actions with redirectAction and prg pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752160/send-data-between-actions-with-redirectaction-and-prg-pattern)